# Why do I get ReferenceError: RTCPeerConnection is not defined in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webapi

I am trying to `const pc = new RTCPeerConnection()` while I get `ReferenceError: RTCPeerConnection is not defined`. How can I overcome this error?

It is not my browsers, I can run `webRTC` natively on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next.js [pre-renders every page](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering) on the server. Trying to use Web APIs when the page gets pre-rendered will throw an error like the one you're seeing since those Web APIs are not present in a Node.js environment.

To solve it, make sure you call `new RTCPeerConnection()` within your component's `useEffect` so it only gets called on the client-side.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const pc = new RTCPeerConnection()
    // Rest of your logic here
}, [])
```

Comment: Appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i achieve to clear all my warnings and errors in order to deal with next.js ssr and RTCPeerConnection.

firstly i declare webRTC only on the client and create a Provider to share some information through the app

```
const webRTC = typeof window != "undefined" ? new RTCPeerConnection(servers) : null;
const WebRTCContext = createContext({});

const WebRTCProvider: React.FC<React.PropsWithChildren> = ({
  children,
}: any) => {
....
}
```

and then i added on the layout

```
import { WebRTCProvider } from "../providers/WebRTCProvider";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
              <WebRTCProvider>
                <Navbar />
                <RoutingNavLayout />
                {children}
              </WebRTCProvider>
      <body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

or else you have to put  all the RTCPeerConnection logic that runs on the client side component and also import it dynamic with the option ssr: false

```
const VideoCallSpaceComponent = dynamic(() => import('@/src/routes/videoSpace'), {
  ssr: false,
});
```