# using ChartIQ in nextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chartiq

I have recently downloaded the trial version of ChartIQ SDK from [here](https://cosaic.io/chartiq-sdk-library-download/) and it is working fine on a React project. But when i switched to Next.js, some features are not usable anymore.
I'm facing three problems on my Next.js project.

1. `CIQ.Studies` is undefined so I cannot add studies to my chart.
2. Also `stxx.changeVectorType` is undefined so I cannot use drawing tools.
3. And only candleSticks , mountain and line types are available.

I am using the same `chartiq-8.3.0.tgz` file both on my React and Next projects and it is all working fine on React but I am experiencing what I just said on Next.js. Can anyone help with me with possible solutions on that?

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [Why do I get ReferenceError: RTCPeerConnection is not defined in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68846372/1870780)? Make sure you call ChartIQ methods within a `useEffect` so it only gets called on the client-side.

Comment: @juliomalves hi thanks for your reply. but this was no exactly the problem. I contacted chartIQ tech support and the solution was to include advance.js file instead of chartiq.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted chartIQ technical support. And the solution is to include `advance.js` instead of `chartiq.js`

Answer (score 0):

Nextjs load libraries on server side, where CHARTIQ is client library that works with document object on the browser.
You need to import the libraries with **SSR (Server Side Rendering) disabled**

doc : https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr